# Find total number of Equal Partition

Tags: integer, partition, number-theory, sieve

For a number N  f(N) = the total number of parts in the partitions of N into equal parts.

For example
if the given number is 4, the equal partitions will be:

{1,1,1,1}   ->total parts=4

{2,2}        -> total parts=2

{4}           -> total parts=1

So,  the total number of parts in the partition of 4 into equal parts is 7.

I got this question in a practice interview question. Want to know how to solve this using programming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question essentially asks for the [divisor sum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) of the number N, since each different divisor d of N can be used to create a different partition of N into equal parts (N / d parts of value d, or d parts of value N / d, whichever you prefer). Since N / d for any divisor d of N is just another divisor, you can simply sum the divisors themselves instead of summing N / d.

Hence you need to choose one of the many ways of computing the divisors for your given number N. For example, RosettaCode has [a section on computing the proper divisors of a number](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Proper_divisors), which is almost what you need (you just have to add N to the divisor set since the proper divisors don't include N itself). Once you have to set of divisors you can compute the desired result (or sum each divisor as it is computed so that there's no need to store the divisors).